# Iframe приложения для facebook, на чем присать

Tags: iframe, facebook-api

Здравствуйте! Подкажите на чем лучше писать iframe приложения для facebook? Находил много примеров мелких приложений, одни на js другие на php. Не пойму, это зависить от разработчика или есть все же какие-то "критерии" для разработки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iframe - это я бы назвал браузер в браузере, так что Вы можете писать на чем угодно, смотря что за приложение, есть моменты, которые не реализуешь на чистом js, так что советую писать на js и php, не забываем про ajax